# Unable to start GWT SuperDev mode within IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.2 Error running GWTKafka SuperDev Mode: No GWT modules found

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

I am trying to start SuperDev mode in IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.2. Even if I untick checkbox Use Super Dev Mode I'll have same message:

```
Error running GWTKafka SuperDev Mode: No GWT modules found in 'gwtkafka'
```

Project is setup as GWT Maven project, practically with no changes away from setup. Project structure

```
gwt
    gwt-client
    gwt-server
    gwt-shared
```

Maven `install` command is working as expected, project is compiled.

[image]

Comment: Is your module descriptor located in src/main/resources?

Answer (score 0):

> Even if I untick checkbox Use Super Dev Mode

Sometimes IntelliJ won't correctly update your Run configuration when switching from Super Dev Mode to normal Dev Mode. I've had that problem before and solved it by creating a fresh Dev Mode configuration.

Aside from that, your config looks very much like mine and I use it every day w/o problems. The only difference is that I kept the "Dev Mode parameters" in the configuration (bindAdress, port etc.) and specified a start page. Maybe try adding the Dev Mode parameters back?